# How can I have columns like this in CSS? (image)

Tags: html, css, css-float

Can Someone please let me know how can I have this done in CSS?

[image: Example]

**EDIT**

The three columns will contain text. I need the black box to be fixed in size and the two fuchsia columns to expand as needed. **Of couse the text shouldn't be hidden in the left and right one because of the black box.** I need it to be wrapped around the black box from both sides.

Comment: You need to provide more details. For instance, how should each column behave regarding the amount of content it contains?

Comment: Many ways really, depending if you want image results, css + image results, css + browser-specific results, etc... What are your requirements?

Comment: I edited the post with more details. Thanks.

Comment: @emurad - Wow, that's some edit.

Comment: See this [ALA article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/crosscolumn/).

Comment: @emurad: Are you still looking for a better answer to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/ffb55/2/

The rounded corner will work in non-IE browser, if you want the rounded corner in IE, follow this example: http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers

**HTML**

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="center"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left {
 float:left;   
 width:50px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:pink;
}

#right {
 float:left;   
 margin-left: 10px;
 left: 100px;
 width:50px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:pink;
}

#center {
  position:absolute;
  left:40px;
  top: 20px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:black;

}

#left, #right, #center {
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Show me some rounded corners and I'll upvote you. Also, post your code on SO too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS representation of your image but without knowing the expected initial scale and how you expect content to reflow in these columns, this CSS isn't going to be very helpful to you.

- Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/PMY7S/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="col lft"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col top"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div { border-radius:1em; }
.col { float:right; width:45%; height:30em; background:#ff3ca0; }
.lft { margin:0 0 0 10%; }
.top { top:5em; left:-5em; width:10em; height:15em; margin:0 0 0 50%; background:#333; position:absolute; }
#wrap { width:20em; margin:1em auto; }
```